# How do I block "you missed a call from..." messages for blocked spam calls?

Tags: android-10, spam

Android does a great job of blocking spam callers. However, my phone provider sends me messages when I miss calls, so while I don't receive the spam calls themselves I always receive these follow-up sms in my inbox;

[image]

Note that while this SMS is sent by my phone provider (Telstra) the number appears as the number of the caller (in this case 02 9133 5694), not the number of my phone provider.

I don't want to disable these SMS as they're genuinely useful to receive when I miss calls from people I actually know. Also, clearly Android knows that this message is related to a spam caller, since it has flagged the message, so how can I get Android to just block these messages?

Comment: "*clearly Android knows that this message is related to a spam caller, since it has flagged the message*" actually, it's flagged because other users flagged SMS from this number (Telstra) as spam, not because it's related to a spam caller :/

Comment: @AndrewT. I think you misunderstand how this works. The number that you're seeing is the number of the spam caller, not Telstra. When I get a missed call from a friend, the SMS shows up as coming from the friend, even though it was sent by Telstra, and it is not marked as spam.

Comment: Ah, I see, consider [edit]ing to clarify it since once I faced that some official marketing SMS from my call provider even got marked as spam.

Comment: @AndrewT. I've added a sentence to clarify this.